# Shared preference is not working with android lockscreen

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have modified the default android lock screen with some tweaks . 
I have use a shared preference in the lock screen to show an overlay text when the phone is booting for the first time . I am getting the overlay in first boot and saving the shared preference value to false . And throughout that session i am able to read the value of the shared preference . But when i restart the phone it seems like the shared preference is resetting

```
    private Boolean mShowOverlay;
    private  final String SHOW_OVERLAY = "showoverlay";
    private SharedPreferences myPrefs ;
    myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    mShowOverlay = myPrefs.getBoolean(SHOW_OVERLAY, true);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(SHOW_OVERLAY, false);
    prefsEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are committing the SharedPreference, I mean calling commit() method??

Comment: yes i have committed.The package name is com.android.internal.policy.impl . But i haven't found this in data/data while exploring the device